# Syntax for making a custom `Import` converter with parameters?

Tags: import, customization

The machinery for `Import` allows [custom converters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) to be defined for importing different file formats. The examples in the link provide details for writing such a converter:

```
ImportExport`RegisterImport["myFmt", {
  (*register the import of sub-elements*)
  {"Header", s_String} :> (myFmtImportHeader[s][##] &),
  {"Data", s_String} :> (myFmtImportData[s][##] &),
  (*register default*)
  myFmtDefaultImporter}, {}]

myFmtDefaultImporter[file_String, opts___?OptionQ] := 
 Module[{data, header},
  header = fnHeader[file, opts];
  data = fnData[file, opts];
  {"Header" -> header, "Data" -> data}]
```

Here, the sub-elements are hooked in as sub-values:

```
myFmtImportHeader[s_String][file_String, opts___?OptionQ] :=
  Module[{header}, header = myFmtReadHeader[file, opts];
         "Header" -> header]
```

**My question is, what should the syntax look like for more complicated functions that take parameters?** For instance, the built-in TIFF routines can handle various specifications for elements and parameters, such as:

```
Import["ExampleData/lena.tif", {"TIFF", "Thumbnail", Tiny}]
Import["ExampleData/lena.tif", {"TIFF", "Thumbnail", {1,1}}]
Import["ExampleData/lena.tif", {"TIFF", "ThumbnailList", 1, Tiny}]
```

If I have an import function:

```
fnReadImages[file_, frames_, opts___]
```

How can I register it so I can call it with something like:

```
Import[file, {"myFmt", "Images", frames}]
```

where frames is an integer, list of integers, or a keyword passed to the function?

Answer (score 5):

`RegisterImport` has specific requirements for the form of the output returned by conditional raw importers:

> The output of the low-level function must match the form
>   {elem->{subelem->output}}.

The following syntax seems to work for specifying a single parameter:

```
ImportExport`RegisterImport["myFmt", {"Header", s_String} :> (myFmtImportHeader[s][##] &),
                            myFmtDefaultImporter}, {}]

myFmtImportHeader[s_String][file_String, opts___?OptionQ] :=
  Module[{header},
   Switch[s,
     "val1", header = {dummy1, s},
     "val1", header = {dummy2, s},
     _, header = "---ERROR---"];
   {"Header" -> {s -> header}}]

Import[file, {"myFmt", "Header", "val1"}]
(* {dummy1, val1} *)
```

So far I haven't been able to extend this to use more than one parameter, as in the third Import TIFF example in the question text.